# Загрузка из файла

Tags: c++

Нужно сгенерировать последовательность, записать ее в файл и загрузить из файла. В файл данные записываются правильно, а вот при загрузке правильно считываются только последние элементы, а 2-й, 3-й и 4-й  всегда равны 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

FILE *f;

void GenKey_G2(unsigned char *K, int LenK) //Генерация
{
    for(int i = 0; i<LenK; i++)
        K[i] = rand();
}
void Show(unsigned char *K, int LenK){ //Вывод на экран в 16-м виде
    cout<<"Последовательность: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i<LenK; i++)
        cout<<hex<<(int)K[i]<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
}
void Save(FILE *f, unsigned char *K, int LenK){ //Запись в файл
    if((f = fopen("rand.txt", "wt"))==NULL){
        printf("Не удается открыть файл\n");
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<LenK; i++){
        fprintf(f, "%x ", K[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("Последовательность сохранена\n");
}
void Upload(FILE *f, unsigned char *K, int LenK){ //Загрузка из файла
    if((f = fopen("rand.txt", "rt"))==NULL){
        printf("Не удается открыть файл\n");
        return;
    }
    while(!feof(f)){
        fscanf(f, "%x ", K);
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("Загрузка прошла успешно\n");
    Show(K, LenK);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    int LenK = 10;
    unsigned char *K = new unsigned char[LenK];
    GenKey_G2(K, LenK);
    Show(K, LenK);
    Save(f, K, LenK);
    Upload(f, K, LenK);
    delete[]K;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(f, "%x ", K);` - попробуйте объяснить что делает этот фрагмент.

Comment: Считывает из файла шестнадцатиричные числа.

Comment: @Lina: Можете подтвердить это текстом из документации? Подсказка: какого типа переменную ожидает `%x`?

Comment: И второй вопрос: на что указывает `K` при каждой операции чтения?

Comment: Если написать так  fscanf(f, "%s ", K); , то результат  чуть лучше, но первые 3 элемента все равно отличаются от исходных.

Comment: "*Если написать...*" - а если вы программируете путём случайного нажатия на клавиши, то лучше сразу бросить это дело...

Comment: klopp, что же по вашему нужно изменить в этом фрагменте?

Comment: Прежде чем разбираться с форматом - попробуйте понять куда именно вы читаете данные. У вас `K` при каждом чтении указывает на одно и то же место в памяти! Ну и скоро уже устану повторять: прошагайте ваш код в отладчике, смотрите глазами что и куда пишется.

Comment: В фрагменте нужно изменить автора, в первую очередь. klopp совершенно прав, прежде чем нажимать на кнопки неплохо бы подумать, на какие и зачем это делать. В программировании слишком много вариантов можно получить даже в элементарных функциях - метод случайного подбора не будет работать. Попробуйте подумать все таки, чем отличается указатель от элемента массива или переменной типа unsigned char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть измените функцию `Upload()`

```
int 
Upload(FILE *f, unsigned char *K, int LenK) //Загрузка из файла
{ 
    if((f = fopen("rand.txt", "rt"))==NULL){
        printf("Не удается открыть файл\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int v, i = 0; // вот это надо добавить

    while (i < LenK && fscanf(f, "%x ", &v) == 1)
      K[i++] = v;

    fclose(f);
    printf("Загрузка прошла %sуспешно\n", i == LenK ? "" : "не");
    Show(K, i);

    return i;
}
```

и Вы увидите, что все заработает.

Объявление файла через передачу аргумента (причем передается уже закрытый в Save() файл) выглядит, конечно, странно.

Поэтому лучше было бы написать `Upload()` вот так:

```
int 
Upload(const char *filename, unsigned char *K, int LenK) //Загрузка из файла
{
  FILE *f; 
  if((f = fopen(filename, "rt"))==NULL) {
    ....
  ...
}
```

а вызывать из main так

```
 ....
 if (Upload("rand.txt", K, LenK)) { // OK
 ...
```

Как мне видится, основная проблема у Вас была в том, что в `fscanf` не нашлось формата для считывания `unsigned char` (тип элементов массива `K[]`). Его действительно нет (по крайней мере я такого не помню). Поэтому читаем файл поэлементно (как и записывали) в переменную типа `int` и присваиваем прочитанное значение (на самом деле, конечно же, его младший байт (другими словами `v % 256`)) очередному элементу массива K.

Поскольку память отведена максимум для LenK элементов, то перед чтением проверяем, можно ли читать дальше. Ну, а проверка кода возврата `fscanf()` (см. `man fscanf`) обеспечивает чтение файла до первого некорректного элемента  или преждевременного конца файла (вдруг файл на диске кто-то подредактировал?).

Comment: *основная проблема* - основных проблем было 2: формат и считывание чего-то по адресу первого элемента массива на каждой итерации массива.

Comment: @klopp, ну, с форматом-то (если, конечно ТС ведает что творит (*я, конечно, сомневаюсь*)) все нормально (почему бы и не записывать значения байтов в хексе?). А с попыткой писать в k -- согласен -- проблема, но вот тут я думаю от безуспешных попыток найти формат для чтения байта и дальше -- "напишу хоть что-нибудь" (кстати, я не уверен, что такой fscanf(f, "%x ", K) вообще компилируется...)

Comment: Я и имею в виду формат при чтении. На `%x` gcc 4.8.2 пишет: `warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned char *’ [-Wformat=]`, но собирает.

Comment: @klopp, ну я же и пишу -- `не нашлось формата для считывания unsigned char` -- поэтому такие дикие эксперименты. А так-то очевидно, что нельзя читать в байт форматом для чтения 32-разрадного целого. По моему я что-то такое (конкретно, что читать будем в int) в ответе написал (если ТС не безнадежен, то все поймет, и почитает что-нибудь про организацию памяти (или для начала man внимательно изучит)).

Comment: Судя по `system("PAUSE")` манов там нет :-)

Comment: В любом случае они есть в гугле.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> while(!feof(f)){
>     fscanf(f, "%x ", K);
> }
> ```

```
for (int temp; fscanf(f,"%x",&temp)==1; *(K++)=temp);
```

Answer (score -2):

может быть надо вставить `fscanf(f, "%s ", &K)`?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: Что за бред? Во-первых, `&K` - уже бред. Во-вторых, `%s` не соответствует вопросу.